# Ошибка expected primary-expression before '=' token

Tags: c, arduino

Помогите с данным скетчем.

Выходит ошибка.

```html
/tmp/983278957/F8GB2WUIZ6C1Z3A/F8GB2WUIZ6C1Z3A.ino: In function 'void loop()':

/tmp/983278957/F8GB2WUIZ6C1Z3A/F8GB2WUIZ6C1Z3A.ino:59:14: error: expected primary-expression before '=' token

if (newdata) = true { //если спутники доступны

^

/tmp/983278957/F8GB2WUIZ6C1Z3A/F8GB2WUIZ6C1Z3A.ino:63:14: error: expected primary-expression before '=' token

if (newdata) = false { //если спутники недоступны, движение в тоннеле например

^

/tmp/983278957/F8GB2WUIZ6C1Z3A/F8GB2WUIZ6C1Z3A.ino:68:20: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

void workonspeed() {

^

/tmp/983278957/F8GB2WUIZ6C1Z3A/F8GB2WUIZ6C1Z3A.ino:129:1: error: expected '}' at end of input

}

^

exit status 1
```

Сам Скетч:

```html
//Created by Ilya OG working hardware ultrasonic and gps read

#define lefttrig 13
#define leftecho 12
#define righttrig 9
#define rightecho 8
int leftred = 4;
int leftgreen = 5;
int rightred = 6;
int rightgreen = 7;
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> //эту библиотеку надо скачать
#include <TinyGPS.h> //эту библиотеку надо скачать

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3); // RX, TX от модуля
TinyGPS gps;

void gpsdump(TinyGPS gps);
void printFloat(double f, int digits = 2);

void setup() {
mySerial.begin(9600);
pinMode(lefttrig, OUTPUT); //инициируем как выход
pinMode(leftecho, INPUT); //инициируем как вход
pinMode(righttrig, OUTPUT); //инициируем как выход
pinMode(rightecho, INPUT); //инициируем как вход
pinMode(leftred, OUTPUT);
pinMode(leftgreen, OUTPUT);
pinMode(rightred, OUTPUT);
pinMode(rightgreen, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(leftgreen, HIGH) ; // led system diagnostic
digitalWrite(leftred, HIGH) ; // led system diagnostic
digitalWrite(rightgreen, HIGH) ; // led system diagnostic
digitalWrite(rightred, HIGH) ; // led system diagnostic
delay(2000);
digitalWrite(leftgreen, LOW) ; // led system diagnostic
digitalWrite(rightgreen, LOW) ; // led system diagnostic
delay(2000);
digitalWrite(leftred, LOW) ; // led diagnostic ok
digitalWrite(rightred, LOW) ; // led diagnostic ok

}
unsigned int impulseTimeleft=0;
unsigned int distanceleft=0;
unsigned int impulseTimeright=0;
unsigned int distanceright=0;

void loop() {
bool newdata = false;
unsigned long start = millis();

if (mySerial.available()) {
char c = mySerial.read();

if (gps.encode(c)) {
newdata = true;
}
}

if (newdata) = true { //если спутники доступны
workonspeed(); //запуск программы чтения скорости
}

if (newdata) = false { //если спутники недоступны, движение в тоннеле например
sonarleft (); //запуск программы левого сонара
sonarright ();
}

void workonspeed() {
if (gps.f_speed_kmph()>10){ //если скорость по спутнику более 10кмч
sonarleft (); //запуск программы левого сонара
sonarright ();
}
}

void sonarleft () { //левый сонар, чтение дистанции

digitalWrite(lefttrig, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10); // равный 10 микросекундам
digitalWrite(lefttrig, LOW);
impulseTimeleft=pulseIn(leftecho, HIGH); // Замеряем длину импульса
distanceleft=impulseTimeleft/58; // Пересчитываем в сантиметры

if (distanceleft<=150)
{
digitalWrite(leftred, HIGH) ; // red left led on
delay(2000);
}
else {
digitalWrite(leftred, LOW) ; // red left led off
}

if ((distanceleft>=150) && (distanceleft<350 ))
{
digitalWrite(leftred, HIGH) ; // red left led on
digitalWrite(leftgreen, HIGH) ; // green left led on
}
else {

digitalWrite(leftgreen, LOW) ; // green left led off
}
delay(100);
}

void sonarright() { //правый сонар, чтение данных
digitalWrite(righttrig, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10); // равный 10 микросекундам
digitalWrite(righttrig, LOW);// Отключаем
impulseTimeright=pulseIn(rightecho, HIGH); // Замеряем длину импульса
distanceright=impulseTimeright/58; // Пересчитываем в сантиметры

if (distanceright<=150) // right distance closer 60 cm
{
digitalWrite(rightred, HIGH) ; // red right led on
delay(2000);
}
else {
digitalWrite(rightred, LOW) ; // red right led on
}
if ((distanceright>=150) && (distanceright<350 ))
{
digitalWrite(rightred, HIGH) ; // red right led on
digitalWrite(rightgreen, HIGH) ; // green right led on
}
else {

digitalWrite(rightgreen, LOW) ; // green right led on
}
delay(100);
}
```

Comment: `SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);` - что это??? `void printFloat(double f, int digits = 2);` - что такое `= 2`???

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка синтаксиса в if. Конструкция

```
if (newdata) = true
```

должна выглядеть как

```
if (newdata == true)
```

Comment: Ошибка повторяеться

Comment: @ИльясБадыганов значит вы ее не исправили.

Answer (score 1):

proposed code corrections:

search for: '<<--' to find corrections

```
#define lefttrig 13
#define leftecho 12
#define righttrig 9
#define rightecho 8


int leftred = 4;
int leftgreen = 5;
int rightred = 6;
int rightgreen = 7;


#include <SoftwareSerial.h> //эту библиотеку надо скачать
#include <TinyGPS.h> //эту библиотеку надо скачать

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3); // RX, TX от модуля
TinyGPS gps;

void gpsdump(TinyGPS gps);
void printFloat(double f, int digits = 2);


void setup()
{
    mySerial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(lefttrig, OUTPUT); //инициируем как выход
    pinMode(leftecho, INPUT); //инициируем как вход
    pinMode(righttrig, OUTPUT); //инициируем как выход
    pinMode(rightecho, INPUT); //инициируем как вход
    pinMode(leftred, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(leftgreen, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(rightred, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(rightgreen, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(leftgreen, HIGH) ; // led system diagnostic
    digitalWrite(leftred, HIGH) ; // led system diagnostic
    digitalWrite(rightgreen, HIGH) ; // led system diagnostic
    digitalWrite(rightred, HIGH) ; // led system diagnostic
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(leftgreen, LOW) ; // led system diagnostic
    digitalWrite(rightgreen, LOW) ; // led system diagnostic
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(leftred, LOW) ; // led diagnostic ok
    digitalWrite(rightred, LOW) ; // led diagnostic ok
}


unsigned int impulseTimeleft =0;
unsigned int distanceleft    =0;
unsigned int impulseTimeright=0;
unsigned int distanceright   =0;

void loop()
{
    bool newdata = false;
    unsigned long start = millis();

    if (mySerial.available())
    {
        char c = mySerial.read();

        if (gps.encode(c))
        {
            newdata = true;
        }
    }

    if (newdata)    // <<-- removed: '= true'
    { //если спутники доступны
        workonspeed(); //запуск программы чтения скорости
    }

    if  (!newdata)  // <<-- replaced: '(newdata) = false'
    { //если спутники недоступны, движение в тоннеле например
        sonarleft (); //запуск программы левого сонара
        sonarright ();
    }
} // <<-- inserted missing close brace '}'


void workonspeed()
{
    if (gps.f_speed_kmph()>10)
    { //если скорость по спутнику более 10кмч
        sonarleft (); //запуск программы левого сонара
        sonarright ();
    }
}


void sonarleft ()
{ //левый сонар, чтение дистанции
    digitalWrite(lefttrig, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10); // равный 10 микросекундам
    digitalWrite(lefttrig, LOW);
    impulseTimeleft=pulseIn(leftecho, HIGH); // Замеряем длину импульса
    distanceleft=impulseTimeleft/58; // Пересчитываем в сантиметры

    if (distanceleft<=150)
    {
        digitalWrite(leftred, HIGH) ; // red left led on
        delay(2000);
    }

    else
    {
        digitalWrite(leftred, LOW) ; // red left led off
    }

    if ((distanceleft>=150) && (distanceleft<350 ))
    {
        digitalWrite(leftred, HIGH) ; // red left led on
        digitalWrite(leftgreen, HIGH) ; // green left led on
    }

    else
    {
        digitalWrite(leftgreen, LOW) ; // green left led off
    }

    delay(100);
}


void sonarright()
{ //правый сонар, чтение данных
    digitalWrite(righttrig, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10); // равный 10 микросекундам
    digitalWrite(righttrig, LOW);// Отключаем
    impulseTimeright=pulseIn(rightecho, HIGH); // Замеряем длину импульса
    distanceright=impulseTimeright/58; // Пересчитываем в сантиметры

    if (distanceright<=150) // right distance closer 60 cm
    {
        digitalWrite(rightred, HIGH) ; // red right led on
        delay(2000);
    }

    else
    {
        digitalWrite(rightred, LOW) ; // red right led on
    }

    if ((distanceright>=150) && (distanceright<350 ))
    {
        digitalWrite(rightred, HIGH) ; // red right led on
        digitalWrite(rightgreen, HIGH) ; // green right led on
    }

    else
    {
        digitalWrite(rightgreen, LOW) ; // green right led on
    }

    delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы ошиблись с синтаксисом. Есть два варианта написания условий для true/false:

1. `if (newdata == true) {//ваш код;} и if (newdata == false) {//ваш код;}`
2. `if (newdata) {//ваш код;} и if (!newdata) {//ваш код;}` соответственно первому 
   методу.

Исправьте все места где вы не правильно написали условия и еще кажется у вас где-то не хватает фигурной скобки.